# How to Install sqlite3-dev libraries for use with Vala?

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite, vala

I had been trying to compile a simple Script written in Vala to retrieve rows from an sqlite db for a personal project. I have tried so hard, even tried to compile the same on virtual machines with different versions of Ubuntu, but still the valac Compiler says

```
error: sqlite3 not found
```

the Compiler instructions were

```
valac --pkg sqlite3 -o sqlitesample SqliteSample.vala
```

I have already installed libsqlite3-dev and sqlite3 packages and also tried compiling and installing sqlite3.13 from source.

I am new to Programming and very new to Vala. I appreciate any help in finding this library playing hide and seek.

Thank You

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/SqliteSample - the code I had been using

Comment: It's the right [Ubuntu package name](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=sqlite3.pc&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any) at least for `xenial`. Did you install the correct architecture (`i386` vs. `amd64`) version of the package?

Comment: BTW: The problem is that valac is looking for the pkgconfig file (called `sqlite3.pc`) and can't find it. That's why I'm asking for the architecture since the arch specific packages install their pkgconfig files in different dirs.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff I have tried installing both amd64 and i386 libraries.Still it doesn't work. I'm using an amd64 based system.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff What do you think the problem might be? Do you think it is a problem with the current system I have? Have you ever had the problem before. Can you mention the exact names of the dev library packages for use of sqlite3 in vala and their locations.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that there was some conflict going on with the libsqlite3-dev package installing in my system - Half the package was installed but then it stops somehow during apt-get.

I downloaded the same package from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libsqlite3-dev) and used

```
dpkg --force-all -i
```

to force install the package. Running the same Compile command got it working.

Thank you so much @JensMühlenhoff for trying to help me solve the problem. Wasted a day trying to find the culprit :/

Comment: Glad you found it :), but this question is unhelpful for future readers, so I'm voting to close it.